# For by property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I have an array like this

```
var myArray = [
    {name: 'A', y: 10}, 
    {name: 'B', y: 20},
    {name: 'C', y: 5}
];
```

it's possible sort the array and preserve the original indexs?

Example:

show the array by y property:

'C',
'A',
'B'

show the array by index:

'A',
'B',
'C'

I hope you can help me. Thanks for read.

Comment: You can make the index part of the information, e.g. `{name: 'A', y: 10, index: 0}`, then sort and display as needed. You cannot sort yet keep indices unchanged.

Comment: ... or just shallow-clone the array before you sort it: `original = myArray.slice()`

Answer (score 1):

You can map your array to preserve indexes in array objects:

```
var myArray = [
    {name: 'A', y: 10}, 
    {name: 'B', y: 20},
    {name: 'C', y: 5}
];
myArray = myArray.map(function(item, index) {
    item.index = index;
    return item;
});
```

and then sort it:

```
myArray.sort(function(i1, i2) {
    return i1.index > i2.index;
});
myArray.sort(function(i1, i2) {
    return i1.y > i2.y;
});
```

Comment: usual warnings about internet explorer not supporting newer JS like `Object.assign`

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to sort by a property:

```
var sortBy = function(prop){
  return function(el1, el2){
    return el1[prop]>el2[prop];
  };
};
```

then you can order by the property `y` of your array with `myArray.sort(sortBy('y'))`, or by `name` with `myArray.sort(sortBy('name'))`. You can access by index with the original array. Or you can add a new property called index like madox2 says.

Comment: Array.prototype.sort() sorts in-place. So you have to clone original array to preserve indexes.

Comment: yeah, you are right. Or you can make a copy with `slice` before call sort. I mean `var sortedByY = myArray.slice().sort(sortBy('y'));`

Answer (score 1):

Sorting with map in a function who takes care of the type of sorting. Returns a new array with the references to the original objects.

```js
function sort(array, key, isString) {
    return array.map(function (_, i) { return i; }).sort(
        isString ?
            function (a, b) { return array[a][key].localeCompare(array[b][key]); } :
            function (a, b) { return array[a][key] - array[b][key]; }
    ).map(function (i) { return array[i]; });
}

var myArray = [
        { name: 'B', y: 20 },
        { name: 'C', y: 5 },
        { name: 'A', y: 10 }
    ];

document.write('<pre>sort by name: ' + JSON.stringify(sort(myArray, 'name', true), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>sort by y: ' + JSON.stringify(sort(myArray, 'y'), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>original array: ' + JSON.stringify(myArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```